# What is the punishment given for using filthy and vulgar language towards women

Tags: women, sin

What's the punishment given for abusing, using filthy vulgar language towards wife and children according to  scriptures?

Comment: @Nirmohi But neither you and nor duplicate link gives the answer of his question. No one explained the punishment for this sin. Hence voted to reopen the post.